# Binding a customized DataGridView with SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, gridview, data-binding

I'm currently writing a WinForms application and I want to use a `DataGridView`. I know how to bind the `DataGridView` with a table in database like this:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WF_AbsPres.Properties.Settings.Default.DbConnectionString))
{
    SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM DevInOut", con);
    SqlCommandBuilder comdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(a);

    DataTable t = new DataTable();
    //t.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    a.Fill(t);

    //dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

    bindingSource1.DataSource = t;

    /// bind the grid view with binding source
    dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader);
    dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;

    dataGridView1.DataSource = t;
    con.Close();
}
```

But the thing is in this way the `dataGridView` shows all the columns of the table. I want to add the columns in dataGridViewmanually and bind each one to a specific column in the database table. It means I don't want some columns to be shown.

How can I do that? Thanks

Comment: `Do you know what SELECT *` means ..? you are selecting the all the columns..

Comment: Needs to understand basci SQL as well as needs to show more effort
I bet if you look at the `Related` Link to the right on this page you could find the answer.. SHOW SOME EFFORT

Comment: Aha you're right,thanks. One questions : My table in database has fields like this :ID,time,date,... but I want the headers in grid view to be shown in another language say farsi. how can I do that?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.**Show some effort**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello for hiding columns in `dataGridView` you can use for example this code:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < (TotalNumberOfColumnsInYourTable; i++)
        {

            {
                dataGridView1.Columns[i].Visible = false;

            }

        }

            //visible columns
        dataGridView1.Columns["ColumnName"].Visible = true;
```

For changing `header` text you can use this:

```
dataGridView1.Columns["OriginalColumnName"].HeaderText = "YourNewName";
```

If you would like to improve only `SqlDataAdapter` just change it to this:

```
 SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT column1,column2,column3.. FROM DevInOut", con);
```

But this means that future work with columns which aren't selected wouldn¨t be possible through `datagridview`. I wouldn't recommend it to you.

Answer (score 0):

Several options:

- Select only data you need from database
- Copy data into another data source that only has columns you want to see displayed
- Customized the grid view (there should be AutoGenerateColumns property you need to set to False) and manually set column names for each column
- Set some columns as invisible like Marek already suggested